# Why is there no semicolon after a macro call?

Tags: syntax, rust

I am following some tutorial I found on Rust, and I ran across something that my Java/C/C++ mind cannot comprehend:

```
impl fmt::Display for Matrix {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "({}, {})\n({}, {})", self.0, self.1, self.2, self.3)
    }
}
```

I don't understand the lack of semicolon at the end of the `write!` macro call. I get an error from the compiler if I add it.
I am guessing that if the semicolon is not there then the `Result` from `write!` is used as return value of `fmt`, but can anybody provide a more specific explanation to why that is and if it always applies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `write` macro uses the `write_fmt()` method either from [`std::fmt::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Write.html) or from [`std::io::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html); both return `Result<(), Error>` and you need to omit the semicolon in order to have it as the output of `fmt()`.

from [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/functions.html), 1st edition:

> Rust functions return exactly one value, and you declare the type
> after an ‘arrow’, which is a dash (-) followed by a greater-than sign
> (>). The last line of a function determines what it returns. You’ll
> note the lack of a semicolon here. If we added it in we would
> get an error.
>
> This reveals two interesting things about Rust: it is an
> expression-based language, and semicolons are different from
> semicolons in other ‘curly brace and semicolon’-based languages.